# Webpack config object validation error: "loader" must be a string

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack Validator to validate my Webpack Config object and it's giving me the following error:

```
[1] "loader" must be a string
```

Here is my Webpack config object:

```js
const config = webpackValidator({
  context: resolve('client'),
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
    vendor: ['./app.css'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: ifProd('bundle.[name].[chunkhash].js', 'bundle.[name].js'),
    path: resolve('dist'),
    pathinfo: ifNotProd(),
  },
  devtool: ifProd('source-map', 'eval'),
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/},
      {test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ['babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/},
      {
        test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: removeEmpty([
    new ProgressBarPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin(ifProd('styles.[name].[chunkhash.css]', 'styles.[name].css')),
    ifProd(new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin()),
    ifProd(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendor', 'manifest'],
    })),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      inject: 'head',
    }),
  ]),
})
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: verify loader section of ExtractTextPlugin.extract. It should be use not loader

Answer (score 0):

The first attribute of "module" is loader while is should be rules.

```
module: {
      rules: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          loaders: ['babel-loader'],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          loaders: ['babel-loader'],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
            loader: 'css-loader'
          })
        },
      ],
    },
```

Also, in order to avoid repetition the two first code rules could be just one with the
`test: /\.(jsx|js)$/`